# How to create an empty array in a matrix

Tags: matlab

How to create an empty array in matlab that accepts elements from a matrix when you do not know the no.of elements it is going to contain ?

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=how+to+create+an+empty+matrix+in+matlab) search should have helped you if you had done it.

Comment: I agree @ParagS.Chandakkar, however, I am surprised that Mathworks doesn't talk about various ways to add stuff to / expand an empty matrix. They do touch upon array concatenation but `end+1` technique is not to be found.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[]` operator. Example:

```
x = [];
```

If you wanna be specific in the **type** of the empty matrix, use the `empty` property. Examples:

```
emptyDoubleMatrix = double.empty; % Same as emptyDoubleMatrix = [];
emptySingleMatrix = single.empty;
emptyUnsignedInt8Matrix = uint8.empty;
```

This works for empty matrices of classes as well. Example:

```
emptyFunctionHandleMatrix = function_handle.empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the empty matrix/vector notation, `[]`, and Matlab will set up a placeholder for it.

```
x = []
```

Now if you want to append a scalar, say `num`, to it, you cannot index it because it is empty.

However, you can either:

1. Use array concatenation to concatenate itself with another scalar:

   ```
   x = [x num]
   ```
2. Use the `end+1` notation, to address the first available location:

   ```
   x(end+1) = num
   ```

Both of the above two notations also work when you want to append a row or a column vector to an existing row vector or column vectors. But when you are concatenating vectors/matrices, remember to be consistent with the dimensions.